# how to include max in sql where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have to create a query to return a next installment date and have a problem with condition when there is a record with no next date (e.g. already paid) but I still need to return that record. Installments payments are every 30 days. Like that:

```
SELECT u.idloan, t.instdate 
FROM   loans u, schedule t 
WHERE  t.instdate IS NOT NULL
AND    (t.instdate > CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),102) 
AND    t.instdate < DateAdd(DAY, 30, GetDate()) 
AND    t.loanid= u.idloan
ORDER BY u.idloan
```

With query above I get the loan next payment date but but no records with loans already paid. I was thinking about adding:

```
or max (t.instdate) <  convert(varchar,getdate(),102)
```

But getting error cannot include max in where clause.
Any work around?  Working on SQL Server 2012.

Thanks.

Comment: Why for the love of god are you converting all your dates to varchars before comparing them?

Comment: Can we get sample starting data and desired results, please?

Comment: Seconding @NielsKeurentjes's question. You've got `CAST(x AS date)` available to you since SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING  max(t.instdate) <  convert(varchar,getdate(),102)
```

Comment: Given that the desired condition is an `OR`, this won't work exactly, due to it functioning as an `AND`.  You do have to use the `HAVING` clause for aggregates, though (or from a subquery), so something along these lines.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. *How* would you use the HAVING clause? What would be the grouping criteria?

Comment: I wonder why such an obviously wrong answer (it won't even run!) gets 3 upvotes ...